# How to append extracted multiple values with comma to new variable?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="dev.com,dev-secret;qa.com,qa-secret"
HOSTNAME=""
SECRET=""


  IFS=';' read -ra host <<<"$HOSTS"
  for i in "${host[@]}"; do
    IFS=',' read -r name secret <<<$i
    HOSTNAME+= ${name}
    SECRET+= ${secret}
  done
```

Now I would like the output as:

```
echo $HOSTNAME should output : "dev.com\,qa.com" 
echo $SECRET should output : "dev-secret\,qa-secret"
```

How can I join or append the for loop output in a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the space after `+=`. With Parameter Expansion you can add `\,` only when the parameter is filled.

```
HOSTS="dev.com,dev-secret;qa.com,qa-secret"
HOSTNAME=""
SECRET=""

IFS=';' read -ra host <<<"$HOSTS"
for i in "${host[@]}"; do
  IFS=',' read -r name secret <<<$i
  HOSTNAME+="${HOSTNAME:+\,}${name}"
  SECRET+="${SECRET:+\,}${secret}"
done

echo "${HOSTNAME}"
echo "${SECRET}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Without looping, but reading arrays and performing array join:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

hosts="dev.com,dev-secret;qa.com,qa-secret"
hostnames=()
secrets=()

join () {
  printf %s "$1"
  shift
  printf %s "${@/#/\\,}"
}

{
  IFS=',' read -r -d';' -a hostnames
  IFS=',' read -r -a secrets
} <<<"$hosts"

printf 'Hostnames: "%s"\n' "$(join "${hostnames[@]}")"
printf 'Secrets: "%s"\n'  "$(join "${secrets[@]}")"
```

Output:

```
Hostnames: "dev.com\,dev-secret"
Secrets: "qa.com\,qa-secret"
```